# Computer vision question relating harris corner detector; not detecting properly endpoints

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, corner-detection

Input image:

[image: Input image]

Code used:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

# Read the image and convert to grayscale
image = cv2.imread('input.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, True)

    # Draw approximated polygon
    for ap in approx:
        cv2.circle(image, tuple(ap[0]), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)

# Display the result
cv2_imshow(image)
```

Output:

[image: Input output wrong]

I've tried using other corner detector methods and some filtering methods such as the gaussian blur without any improvement. Can somebody help me to detect correctly the ending points and the intersection points?

Comment: Compute the skeleton. End points are skeleton points with one neighbor. Intersection points are skeleton points with more than two neighbors.

Answer (score 2):

For a point on the lines i.e. a point that is black in your picture imagine counting the points that are slightly closer to it than the lines are thick. You get the biggest count if you at a crossing and the smallest if you're at an end of a line.

An efficient way to count the points near a point in an image is taking the convolution with ones.

I put some white space around the image:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

mask = img[:,:,0] == 1
widened_img = np.ones([mask.shape[0]+100, mask.shape[1]+100])
widened_img[50:-50, 50:-50] = mask
```

[image: picture with whitespace]

Calculate points that are very dark in the convolution:

```
def scatter(y,x):
    plt.scatter(x,y)

conv = convolve2d(widened_img, np.ones([15,15]), mode='same', fillvalue=1)
scatter(*np.where(conv<140))
plt.imshow(conv, cmap='gray')
```

[image: Convolution with dark points marked]

Finally I plot the convolution with very light points marked that are not white in the original image:

```
conv = convolve2d(widened_img, np.ones([15,15]), mode='same', fillvalue=1)
scatter(*np.where((conv>180) & (widened_img <1)))
plt.imshow(conv, cmap='gray')
```

[image: end points]

Comment: Please put all necessary `import` statements in so your code is runnable. Thank you.

Comment: How did you determine 140 and 180? You’d have to adjust those values if the line thickness changes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell added imports

Comment: @CrisLuengo you could probably just count how many points are selected at what values and stop at inflection points or something like that but I don't feel like over engineering this. Seems like there are others around that want to do that with my code anyways.

Comment: My code has just a single line in common with yours, and that line is a convolution with a different size kernel on an image that has been preprocessed completely differently by being thresholded and skeletonised. Both the algorithm and presentation are different and hopefully instructive/useful so I disagree with the suggestion I have somehow taken your code. The upvote on your answer is actually from me too.

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry I didn't mean to say you plagiarized my idea/code. I was just saying the same thing you did: that it is a slightly different implementation of the same idea basic.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented @CrisLuengo's suggestion from the comments. It is pretty similar to Lukas's answer, but I think it should be more tolerant of different line thicknesses because it skeletonises first:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as convolve2d

# Load image, greyscale and threshold
orig   = cv.imread("ySvxY.png")
grey   = cv.cvtColor(orig, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thr = cv.threshold(grey, 127, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Skeletonise image
skel = skeletonize(thr)
cv.imwrite('DEBUG-skeleton.png',skel*255)

# Define 3x3 kernel for counting neighbours
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
print(f'{kernel=}')

# Convolve with ring kernel
conv = convolve2d(skel, kernel, mode='same', fillvalue=1)
scaling = 255/conv.max()
cv.imwrite('result.png', (conv*scaling).astype(np.uint8))

max = conv.max()
print(f'{max=}')
print(np.where(conv==max))
# Make all pixels with "max" neighbours red
orig[conv==max] = [0,0,255]
# Make all pixels with "max-1" neighbours green
orig[conv==(max-1)] = [0,255,0]
cv.imwrite('coloured.png', orig)
```

Here is `DEBUG-skeleton.png`:

[image]

And here is `result.png` which shows pixels with brightness proportional to their number of neighbours, i.e. intersections are brighter:

[image]

And here is the original image but coloured red where pixels have most neighbours, and green where they have nearly the most neighbours:

[image]

---

For some reason, the results are not as expected so I am still looking at that. If anyone has any bright ideas for corrections please edit them in, or add a comment.

Comment: Almost there! Don’t select any pixel in `conv` with a given number of neighbors, only select pixels that are also in `skel`. So something like `skel & (conv>3)` would be the branches and `skel & (conv==2)` would be the end points.

Comment: By the way, `>3` is pixels with more than two neighbors because `conv` counts the central pixel too. You could set the central pixel in `kernel` to 0 to only count neighbors.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Actually, I originally had the central pixel of the kernel set to zero - that's why I wrote *"ring kernel"* in the comments. Setting it back to zero and using your suggested checks on the number of neighbours still doesn't produce the correct result though 

Comment: The suggested checks are for the solid kernel. For the “ring kernel” it would be >2 for branch points and ==1 for end points. If it has 1 neigbor it’s an end point. 2 neigbors is on a line, 3 or more neigbors is a branch point (or intersection). By the way, the intersection of two lines often looks like two branch points close together, since we’re in a discrete world where things get weird some times (ie two points with 3 neighbors each rather than one point with  4 neighbors).

Comment: Could the non detection of the end points be related to how the convolution handles points that don't have enough neighbouring pixels for the convolution kernel? That's the reason I added white space in my answer.